# Why does Chrome send four browsers in the user-agent header?

Tags: web-browser, http, chrome, header

I am using Chrome in linux with Version 51.0.2704.63 (64-bit). I recorded a HTTP request of Chrome and here is part of the recording:

```
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.63 Safari/537.36
```

Why does Chrome send four browsers in the user-agent field? Is this a countermeasure to obfuscate the browser version?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Presumably you mean the following four:

1. `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)`
2. `AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko)`
3. `Chrome/51.0.2704.63`
4. `Safari/537.36`

most Web browsers use a User-Agent string value as follows:

```
Mozilla/[version] ([system and browser information]) [platform] ([platform details]) [extensions].
```

- `Mozilla`  is a [byproduct of browser wars](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114254/why-do-all-browsers-user-agents-start-with-mozilla).
- `AppleWebKit/537.36` is the platform used by your browser.
- `Chrome/51.0.2704.63` is your browser
- `Safari/537.36` was added for historic reasons, where Safari was treated differently.

You may wish to also read [this history](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/) or [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4024230/strange-user-agent-with-google-chrome)

Comment: Note, that since 2013 the platform Chrome uses is not WebKit, it's [Blink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blink_(browser_engine)), a fork of WebKit (which in it's turn is a fork of [KHTML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KHTML) KDE lib)